# Responsive sizing with lazy_high_charts gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lazy-high-charts

It is possible for highcharts to perform responsively, as seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrTux/9/).

It seems that lazy_high_charts defaults to `width: 600px; height: 400px;` when no width or height is supplied. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

set height only will do the trick

`LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph', :style=>"height:260px")`

if you preferer you can set width with percentages